# Font metrics in QStyledItemDelegate

Tags: c++, qt, fonts

I need to find out a width of a text (not whole cell, just text) painted in an item of `QTableView` and I need this inside of the overwritten `paint()` method of `QStyledItemDelegate`. What I've tried is:

```
void SqlQueryItemDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    // data
    QString text = displayText(index.data(), option.locale);
    int textWidth = option.fontMetrics.horizontalAdvance(text);
    qDebug() << textWidth;
}
```

...but this gives slightly smaller value than expected. What is printed on DEBUG is 509, while I measured this text on screen to be around 545px:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? How to obtain real width of this text to be painted?

This is under Windows 10 with Qt 5.15.2.

EDIT:
If that matters, here's a full body of the `paint()` method that I implemented:

```
void SqlQueryItemDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
    SqlQueryItem* item = getItem(index);

    if (item->isUncommitted())
    {
        painter->setPen(item->isCommittingError() ? QColor(Qt::red) : QColor(Qt::blue));
        painter->setBrush(Qt::NoBrush);
        painter->drawRect(option.rect.x(), option.rect.y(), option.rect.width()-1, option.rect.height()-1);
    }

    if (item->isLimitedValue())
    {
        QString text = displayText(item->getValue(), option.locale);
        int textWidth = option.fontMetrics.boundingRect(text).width();
        int margin = QApplication::style()->pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_FocusFrameHMargin, nullptr, option.widget) + 1; // from QCommonStyle source code
        if (option.rect.width() >= (textWidth + LOAD_FULL_VALUE_BUTTON_SIZE + 4 + (margin * 2)))
        {
            QStyleOptionButton button = fullValueButtonOption;
            button.rect = getLoadFullValueButtonRegion(option.rect);
            button.state = QStyle::State_Enabled | QStyle::State_MouseOver;
            if (lmbPressedOnButton)
                button.state |= QStyle::State_Sunken | QStyle::State_Active;

            QApplication::style()->drawControl(
                        mouseOverFullDataButton ? QStyle::CE_PushButton : QStyle::CE_PushButtonLabel,
                        &button, painter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the horizontal advance is *not* the same as the text width.  You might be better off with something like `option.fontMetrics.boundingRect(text).width()` .

Comment: I've tried that one too, but it returned 508, so not any better.

Comment: Your code can not match the output since your paint() method does not draw anything.

Comment: I did shorten it for the sake of example here, but now I posted also full code.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!

I needed to have my local copy of options first and initialize it, before measuring anything:

```
QStyleOptionViewItem opt = option;
initStyleOption(&opt, index);
int textWidth = opt.fontMetrics.boundingRect(text).width();
```

Only after initializing the option, the font inside it was changed to the actual font used for rendering (I verified it in debug, the font was changed) and both `horizontalAdvance()` and `boundingRect()` return correct width.

Earlier I assumed incorrectly, that the option passed to the `paint()` method is already initialized. That is not true.